# Carousel image source won't link to images, images won't show on webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I have tried everything.  I have tried putting the images in the folder of the file being linked to and I have tried every path possible to link the src=""

Code without <>:

```
img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide"
```

With the image in the folder of the file--

Code without <>:

```
img class="d-block w-100" src="image.jpeg" alt="First slide"
```

with the image in /app/assets/images

Code without <>:

```
img class="d-block w-100" src="/../../app/assets/images/image.jpeg" alt="First slide"
```

and just for the hell of it I have tried every path in-between.

I can't get a single image to be shown on the carousel.

Thanks in advance, this is a stupid problem I can't solve.

Comment: As escanxr says, you should be using an `image_tag` helper. It looks like you have some fundamental problems with understanding how to use the `image_tag` helper. You might find [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails+image_tag) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a relative path with rails. :)

If your image is in `assets/images`, you just have to do:

```
image_tag 'image.jpeg', class: 'd-block w-100', alt: 'first-slide'
```

And for example, if your image is in a folder, like `assets/images/customer/image.jpeg` the code will be:

```
image_tag 'customer/image.jpeg', class: 'd-block w-100', alt: 'first-slide'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I am still messing it up.  Here is my code, I am trying to put in your code to make it work but I am still getting the same error.      <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="image.jpeg" alt="First slide">
    </div>   I don't think I know how to put in your code to make it work.

Comment: When you put my code, the code generated in the view is what you have pasted but there's no image displayed?

Comment: no image displayed. <img image_tag=image.jpeg class="d-block w-100" alt="First slide">, something weird with the single quotes maybe?

Comment: Oh no, it's an helper so you don't need the img element. You just need to put `<%= image_tag 'image.jpeg', class: 'd-block w-100', alt: 'first-slide' %>` and rails will generate the img element for you. And the single quotes are just a convention

Comment: THANK YOU!!  long story short this is the code that worked with the images in the asset/images folder :       <%= image_tag 'grand_canyon_1.jpeg', class: 'd-block w-100', alt: 'first-slide' %>

Comment: Nice @g.maxgudmundson enjoy Rails ✌️